# Linearizing the trigonometric functions or: Squaring the circle by Fourier transformation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, reference-request, approximation

It's an easy exercise to approximate the cosine and the sine function by a piecewise linear function on the unit interval $[0,1]$. Let $\tau = 2\pi$.

Let

$$\boxed{\cos_\bigcirc(x) = \cos(\tau x)\\\sin_\bigcirc(x) = \sin(\tau x)}$$

and compare this to

$$\boxed{\cos_\square(x) = \begin{cases}
+1 & \text{ for } \frac{0}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{8} \\
+2 - 8x & \text{ for } \frac{1}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{8} \\
-1  & \text{ for } \frac{3}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{5}{8} \\
-6 + 8x & \text{ for } \frac{5}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{7}{8} \\
+1 & \text{ for } \frac{7}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{8}{8} \\
\end{cases}
\\ \\\sin_\square(x) = \begin{cases}
+0 + 8x & \text{ for } \frac{0}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{8} \\
+1 & \text{ for } \frac{1}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{3}{8} \\
+4 - 8x & \text{ for } \frac{3}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{5}{8} \\
-1 & \text{ for } \frac{5}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{7}{8} \\
-8 + 8x & \text{ for } \frac{7}{8} \leq x \leq \frac{8}{8} \\
\end{cases}}$$

These are the plots:

[image]

### Observations

- It may come as a surprise or not that while $\cos_\bigcirc(x)$ and $\sin_\bigcirc(x)$ yield the unit circle by $x_\bigcirc(x) = \cos_\bigcirc(x)$ and $y_\bigcirc(x) = \sin_\bigcirc(x)$, the functions  $\cos_\square(x)$ and $\sin_\square(x)$ yield the *unit square* by $x_\square(x) = \cos_\square(x)$ and 
  $y_\square(x) = \sin_\square(x)$. By "unit square" I mean the square with "radius" $1$, not with side length $1$. The unit circle in the incircle of this square:

[image]

- While the circumference of the unit circle is just the "number of the circle" $\tau$, the circumference of the unit square is $8$ (the "number of the square"). Note how $8$ is used in the definition of $\cos_\square(x)$ and $\sin_\square(x)$, compared to $\tau$ in the definition of $\cos_\bigcirc(x)$ and $\sin_\bigcirc(x)$. Note further that not by accident $8 \approx \tau$ and that not by accident $8 = 3^2 - 1^2$:

[image]

- There are natural generalizations of piecewise linear approximations of the cosine and the sine for arbitrary regular $n$-polygons which will approximate the true functions better and better as the polygons will approximate the circle better and better.
- The tangens $\tan_\bigcirc(x) = \tan(\tau x)$ is very well approximated already by 
  $\tan_\square(x) = \frac{\sin_\square(x)}{\cos_\square(x)}$:

[image]

- The functions $\cos_\square(x)$ and $\sin_\square(x)$ can be used to [parametrize the square spiral](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3162022/1792) analoguous to how $\cos_\bigcirc(x)$ and $\sin_\bigcirc(x)$ can be used to parametrize the Archimedean spiral.

### Questions

> 1. Under which name and in which contexts have the functions
>      $\cos_\square(x)$ and $\sin_\square(x)$ been studied before?
> 2. Is there an elegant and/or more compact way to write the equations for
>      $\cos_\square(x)$ and $\sin_\square(x)$ in one closed expression, e.g.
>      by using the Heaviside function?
> 3. Is there a closed formula for the Fourier transform of $\cos_\square(x)$ and $\sin_\square(x)$ (the "Fourier transform of the quadrature of the circle")?

This is how the Fourier transforms of $\cos_\square(x)$ and $\sin_\square(x)$ look like:
[image]

### Summary

Thanks to user J.M. we now know the Fourier coefficients $\widehat{\cos}_\square(k)$

$$\boxed{\widehat{\cos}_\square(k) = 8 \cdot \begin{cases}
\ \ \ \ \ 0 & \text{ for } k \equiv 0 \mod 2 \\
+(\pi k)^{-2} & \text{ for } k \equiv 1 \mod 8 \text{ or } k \equiv 7 \mod 8\\
-(\pi k)^{-2} & \text{ for } k \equiv 3 \mod 8 \text{ or } k \equiv 5 \mod 8\\
\end{cases}}$$

and $\widehat{\sin}_\square(k)$ accordingly.

Now can perform the squaring of the circle by these steps:

1. Consider $\cos_\bigcirc(x)$ and $\sin_\bigcirc(x)$ which "draw" the unit circle (with diameter $2$).
2. Consider the functions $\cos_\square(x)$ and $\sin_\square(x)$ defined by

$$\cos_\square(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \widehat{\cos}_\square(k)\cos_\bigcirc(kx)\\
\sin_\square(x) := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \widehat{\sin}_\square(k)\sin_\bigcirc(kx)$$

3. The functions $\cos_\square(x)$ and $\sin_\square(x)$ "draw" the unit square (with diameter $2$).

Comment: We have the alternate expression $$\sin_\square(x)=\min\left(\max\left(-1,\frac4{\pi}\arcsin\sin 2\pi x\right),1\right)$$ and your "square cosine" can of course be obtained through a translation.

Comment: Do you have a table of numbers for the fourier series?  I'm poking at it myself but if you've already got it ready to go then that'd help a lot.

Comment: Since your square cosine is an even function, the coefficients of the sines in your Fourier series should be zero. Someone better than me at mathematics should be able to prove this result easily: $$\cos_\square(x)=\frac{8\sqrt 2}{\pi^2}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\binom{j+1}{2}}\cos((2j+1)x)}{(2j+1)^2}$$

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: Looks promising. How did you find the formula?

Comment: By explicitly evaluating the Fourier integrals and noticing a pattern. Now that I have stared at it a bit more, except for the sign pattern, it looks awfully like a [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function).

Comment: Don't you find the factor $\frac{8\sqrt 2}{\pi^2}$ fascinating, combing the number of the square $8$, the number of the circle $\tau = 2\pi$, the root and the squaring function, and the square root of $2$. There's quite a lot in it.

Comment: Note further (but this may be vacuous musings) that $\frac{8\sqrt 2}{\pi^2} = 1.1463... \approx 1.1415... = \pi - 2$.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: You may want to have a look at my answer which tries to clarify your formula a bit.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: Maybe you want to have a look at this [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174514/fourier-series-of-regular-polygons).

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: Let me also point you to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3174587/1792) of mine, which tries to generalize your result above.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: Here's another [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175897/relating-properties-of-shapes-and-their-fourier-series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2, we can do this via floor, absolute value, min, and max.

First, we need a triangle wave.  $\left|x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor - 1/2\right|$ gives a triangle wave of period $1$ and range $[0,1/2]$.  We need range $[-2,2]$ because that's where the diagonals will meet, so multiply by $8$ and subtract $2$:  $8\left|x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor - 1/2\right|-2$.  Then we cut off the top and bottom with min and max:

$$\cos_\square(x) = \min\left(\max\left(-1,8\left|x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor - 1/2\right|-2\right),1\right)$$

THen since $\sin_\square(x)=\cos_\square\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)$ we can just ... do that and get

$$\sin_\square(x) = \min\left(\max\left(-1,8\left|x - \left\lfloor x-1/4 \right\rfloor - 3/4\right|-2\right),1\right)$$

Comment: Marvelous, thank you!

Comment: ...and of course, if you wish, [there are alternate expressions for $\min$ and $\max$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46939).

Answer (score 0):

The work has been done by user J.M. (who seems to be a mathematician of sorts), so let me just put it in order.

First let me rewrite the definition of $\cos_\square(x)$ a bit:

$$\cos_\square(x) = \begin{cases}
+1 & \text{ for } -1 \leq 8x \leq 1 \\
+2 - 8x & \text{ for }\ \ \ \ \ 1 \leq 8x \leq 3 \\
-1  & \text{ for }\ \ \ \ \ 3 \leq 8x \leq 5 \\
-6 + 8x & \text{ for }\ \ \ \ \ 5 \leq 8x \leq7 \\
\end{cases}$$

The unit square has diagonal (= "diameter") $2\sqrt{2}$, so let's normalize $\cos_\square(x)$ by a factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ so the unit square has diameter $2$ (just like the unit circle has diameter $2$):

$$\boxed{\cos_\square(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\begin{cases}
+1 & \text{ for } -1 \leq 8x \leq 1 \\
+2 - 8x & \text{ for }\ \ \ \ \ 1 \leq 8x \leq 3 \\
-1  & \text{ for }\ \ \ \ \ 3 \leq 8x \leq 5 \\
-6 + 8x & \text{ for }\ \ \ \ \ 5 \leq 8x \leq7 \\
\end{cases}}$$

User J.M.'s expression for the Fourier coefficients $\widehat{\cos}_\square(k)$ can then be written in this form:

$$\boxed{\widehat{\cos}_\square(k) = 8 \cdot \begin{cases}
\ \ \ \ \ 0 & \text{ for } k \equiv 0 \mod 2 \\
+(\pi k)^{-2} & \text{ for } k \equiv 1 \mod 8 \text{ or } k \equiv 7 \mod 8\\
-(\pi k)^{-2} & \text{ for } k \equiv 3 \mod 8 \text{ or } k \equiv 5 \mod 8\\
\end{cases}}$$

Answer (score 0):

To those who don't have the function $f(x) = \arcsin(\sin(2\pi x))$ before their inner eye, this is how it looks like:

[image]

It's essentially this function that user J.M. cuts off at $\min = -1$ and $\max = +1$ to yield $\sin_\square(x)$.