# The number $\pi$ in an unexpected context

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, pi, experimental-mathematics

*[This is a follow-up question to this one: [Figures and Numbers: Relating properties of geometric shapes and their Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175897/figures-and-numbers-relating-properties-of-geometric-shapes-and-their-fourier-s).]*

---

Drawing shapes by some predefined Fourier series I found this **square with rounded corners** which is given by the Fourier series

$$a_k = \begin{cases}
 +\pi^{-k} & \text{ for } k \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
 +\pi^{-k} & \text{ for } k \equiv 3 \pmod 4\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$

$$b_k = \begin{cases}
 +\pi^{-k} & \text{ for } k \equiv 1 \pmod 4\\
 -\pi^{-k} & \text{ for } k \equiv 3 \pmod 4\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$

[image]

Compare this to the perfect square given by

$$a_k = \begin{cases}
 +k^{-2} & \text{ for } k \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
 +k^{-2} & \text{ for } k \equiv 3 \pmod 4\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$

$$b_k = \begin{cases}
 +k^{-2} & \text{ for } k \equiv 1 \pmod 4\\
 -k^{-2} & \text{ for } k \equiv 3 \pmod 4\\ 0 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$

[image]

Note that for bases different from $\pi$ in the formulas for $a_k$ and $b_k$, the rounded square hasn't got so "straight" sides anymore, e.g. for base $2.5$ and $4.5$:

[image]

My question is:

> Might it be true, that for base $\pi$ in the formulas for $a_k$, $b_k$
>   above, the resulting shape has "maximally straight" sides? And if so:
>   How to prove it?

First, of course, one has to define what "maximally straight" means.

---

For the sake of comparison here is the unrounded square with exponents $1.5$ and $2.5$ instead of $2$ in the corresponding formulas. As in the case of the rounded square, $2$ (instead of $\pi$) yields the "maximally straight" sides.

[image]

Comment: I guess maximally straight could mean that $\pi$ is the largest base such that the resulting shape is convex. Whether that's true I don't know

Comment: @Banach: Great idea! This might make the question answerable.

Comment: @Banach: I guess you mean the **smallest** base such that the resulting shape is convex.

Comment: Yes, I do. And since we are only interested in the sign of the curvature, which is equal to that of $x'y''-x''y'$, this might actually be feasible

Comment: @Banach: Do you plan to give it a try?

Comment: @Banach: The same proof will show that $2$ is an distinguished number in the case of the unrounded square (see my edit above): It's the smallest exponent such that the resulting shape is convex. (The interchangable roles of "base" and "exponent" is the interesting point, I find.) –

Comment: It looks like $\pi$ doesn't give a convex shape, one can visually check that the line $y=x+0.40065$ cuts the shape in four points, so the shape's "sides" bend inwards. Following Bananach's approach and setting the curvature $K(a,t)$ to zero at $t=\pi/4$, and if WolframAlpha is not mistaken, it seems that the minimum such number is actually $a=\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{15+8\sqrt{3}}} = 3.291795...$, the greatest positive solution to $a^{10}-9a^8-22a^6+22a^4+9a^2-1=0$.

Comment: @pregunton: What a pity! Thanks anyway.