# What is an algorithm to spiral outwards from (0,0) in increments of +/- 1

Tags: algorithms

I need to map a collection onto a grid with an odd width and height (thus it can have a center) in a way that spirals out from the center to an arbitrary size. There's a description [here](https://www.educative.io/answers/spiral-matrix-algorithm) that shows how to spiral inwards through a matrix, but it requires knowing the dimensions of the matrix. I want to spiral *outwards* for *any* number of grid tiles given just the index. For instance, given a grid like this:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (-1,-1) | (0,-1) | (1,-1) |
| (-1,0) | (0,0) | (1,0) |
| (-1,1) | (0,1) | (1,1) |

We have a function `f` that we hardcode an initial direction of `up` (negative y) and a spiral direction of `counterclockwise` such that we can say:

`f(0) = (0,0)`

`f(1) = (0,-1)`

`f(2) = (-1,-1)`

`f(3) = (-1,0)`

And so on to

`f(8) = (1,-1)` and `f(9) = (1,-2)`

Is this even possible to model as a function? Would it have something to do with pi because it's kind of a circle? Every spiral function I can find has curves instead of abrupt whole integer steps. I recall from an algorithms class a couple of years back that clamping stuff to integers sometimes counterintuitively makes computation *less* tractable.

Comment: See Ulam spiral https://oeis.org/A174344

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157030/parametrizing-the-square-spiral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to write the function $f(n)$ in an $O(1)$ form (provided you assume all arithmetic operations, including the `sqrt` function, are $O(1)$).
The spiral consists of sequences of motion up, left, down, or right
in a predictable pattern, so you just have to deduce which sequence of motions the $n$th point is in, how far within that sequence it is, and where that puts it in the coordinate grid.

Here is a non-recursive version of the function $f(n),$ coded in Python 3.

```
# Find the nth set of coordinates in a spiral through
# lattice points starting at 0,0

from math import sqrt, floor, ceil
import numpy as np

# Treating the spiral as a sequence of concentric squares
# around the origin, return the inradius of the square that
# the nth point is on.
def cycle_number(n):
    x = floor(sqrt(n))
    return ceil(x/2)

def first_number_in_cycle(k):
    return 4*k*(k-1) + 1

def side_length_in_cycle(k):
    return 2*k

def point(x,y):
    return np.array([x,y])

corner_vectors = (point(1,-1),point(-1,-1),point(-1,1),point(1,1))
side_directions = (point(-1,0),point(0,1),point(1,0),point(0,-1))

def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return point(0,0)
    k = cycle_number(n)
    distance_from_cycle_start = n - first_number_in_cycle(k)
    # Identify which of the four sides (straight sections)
    # of the cycle n is in:
    side_length = side_length_in_cycle(k)
    side = floor(distance_from_cycle_start / side_length)
    distance_along_side = 1 + distance_from_cycle_start % side_length
    ref_position = k * corner_vectors[side]
    return ref_position + distance_along_side * side_directions[side]

#-----------------------------------------------------------
#  Everything below this point is just to test f(n)

# Assume x and y coordinates range from -3 to 3 inclusive
data_array = np.array([[0] * 7] * 7)
def write_data(p, value):
    x = p[0]
    y = p[1]
    data_array[y + 3, x + 3] = value

def print_data():
    for row in range(7):
        for column in range(7):
            print(f' {data_array[row][column]:3}', end='')
        print('')

for n in range(49):
    p = f(n)
    write_data(p, n)
print_data()
```

Displaying the output in the same coordinate system used in the question
(left-handed Cartesian coordinates with the $y$ axis pointing down and the $x$ axis pointing right), the output looks like this:

```
  30  29  28  27  26  25  48
  31  12  11  10   9  24  47
  32  13   2   1   8  23  46
  33  14   3   0   7  22  45
  34  15   4   5   6  21  44
  35  16  17  18  19  20  43
  36  37  38  39  40  41  42
```

---

As a bonus, if you append the following to the Python code shown above,
you get a function `sequence_number` that takes a pair of coordinates and
returns the value of $n$ such that $f(n)$ is the given pair of coordinates.
That is, `sequence_number` is the inverse of `f`.
Using `sequence_number`, we can produce the same output shown above, but it is computed left to right one row at a time instead of by increasing values of $n.$

```
def taxicab_distance(u,v):
    return max(abs(v[0] - u[0]), abs(v[1] - u[1]))

# Return the value of n such that f(n) has the given coordinates
def sequence_number(p):
    x = p[0]
    y = p[1]
    k = max(x, y, -x, -y) # the cycle number
    side = (3 if x == k
            else 2 if y == k
            else 1 if x == -k
            else 0)
    ref_position = k * corner_vectors[side]
    distance_along_side = taxicab_distance(p, ref_position)
    side_length = side_length_in_cycle(k)
    n = first_number_in_cycle(k) + side * side_length + distance_along_side - 1
    return n

#-----------------------------------------------------------
#  Code to test sequence_number(p)

print('plotting f(n) -> n')
for y in range(-3, 4):
    for x in range(-3, 4):
        p = vector(x,y)
        n = sequence_number(p)
        print(f' {n:3}', end='')
    print('')
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Jean Marie pointed out, the answer is the Ulam (square) spiral. It is a recursive algorithm, I was hoping for a clean O(1) function, but it works! It starts on the right and spirals out clockwise.

*The following is in the Python language.*

```
def ulam_spiral_xy(n):
    if n == 1:
        return (0, 0)
    else:
        x, y = ulam_spiral_xy(n-1)
        return (
            x + int(math.sin(math.floor(math.sqrt(4*n-7))*math.pi/2)), 
            y + int(-math.cos(math.floor(math.sqrt(4*n-7))*math.pi/2))
        )
```

This block of code

```
array = [
        [21,22,23,24,25],
        [20,7,8,9,10],
        [19,6,1,2,11],
        [18,5,4,3,12],
        [17,16,15,14,13]
]

for i in range(1, 26):
        coords = ulam_spiral_xy(i)
        print(array[coords[1] + 2][coords[0] + 2], end = " ")
```

gives us the expected output of
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25`

Comment: FYI for readers who might want to reproduce this themselves, the code is in Python